# DBT : Access Denied to Table dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.orders

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

When I follow the [tutorial of dbt-CLI](https://docs.getdbt.com/tutorial/create-a-project-dbt-cli), I have an error access to the dataset `dbt-tutorial` store on BigQuery when I run: `dbt run` command.

See below :

```sh
$ dbt run
Running with dbt=0.21.1
Found 3 models, 4 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 184 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 0 sources, 0 exposures

15:01:05 | Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
15:01:05 |
15:01:05 | 1 of 3 START table model dbt_username.customers........................ [RUN]
15:01:05 | 1 of 3 ERROR creating table model dbt_adrien.customers............... [ERROR in 0.74s]
15:01:05 | 2 of 3 START table model dbt_username.my_first_dbt_model............... [RUN]
15:01:08 | 2 of 3 OK created table model dbt_adrien.my_first_dbt_model.......... [CREATE TABLE (2.0 rows, 0.0 Bytes processed) in 2.39s]
15:01:08 | 3 of 3 START view model dbt_username.my_second_dbt_model............... [RUN]
15:01:09 | 3 of 3 OK created view model dbt_username.my_second_dbt_model.......... [OK in 0.97s]
15:01:09 |
15:01:09 | Finished running 2 table models, 1 view model in 4.88s.

Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:

Database Error in model customers (models/customers.sql)
  Access Denied: Table dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.orders: User does not have permission to query table dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.orders.
  compiled SQL at target/run/jaffle_shop/models/customers.sql

Done. PASS=2 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=3
```

Answer (score 3):

This error probably occurs because `dbt-tutorial:jaffle_shop.orders` table is not available in location `EU`.

You should use `location:US` in your dbt `profiles.yml` and set "treatment location" to "US" when you create your Big Query account (if not you will have a 404 error).

If you try to run the request in Big Query UI with "EU" location you will get the same error than in dbt-cli :
[image]
[image: big query dbt error]

Comment: Where do I find the screen from the Screenshot to set the treatment location?

Comment: I can run the query in bigquery but in dbt when setting the processing location to us I get the 404 error you are mentioning in your answer.

Comment: Was able to fix by deleting the existing Views in the interface and executing dbt run.